# Django - allow manually setting auto_now attribute for Sub-class

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.10

In our base model (that few model inherit from) we set

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

now, in specific sub-class model I need to override it's save and update the 'created_at':

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        existing_item = Item.objects.active_and_deleted().get(
                                                  identifier=self.identifier)   
        existing_item.created_at = now()
        super(Item, existing_item).save(args, kwargs)
```

That updated instance created_at is 'None'.
I've tried 'editable=True' unsuccessfully.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

With the following example, change the default parameter of `DateTimeField`, django will allow you to edit it manually:  assign the attribute with `django.utils.timezone.now()` in the `save()` method

```
import django

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True,
                   default=django.utils.timezone.now)
```

Comment: Thanks @Lemayzeur. I guess that means that unless I manually set the value, this attribute will be changed on every save, right? If so - the question is what should I do with 'auto_now_add' that supposed to be set only on 'add' (create), as opposed to 'auto_now' that is changed on every save

Comment: when you set `default=django.utils.timezone.now()`  it's like you had set `auto_now_add=True` (create)

Comment: Note that it must be a callable (i.e. `default=django.utils.timezone.now`), otherwise the same timestamp will be used for all instances created in the same Python process. From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default): _"If callable it will be called every time a new object is created"_.